# HDFS No valid image files found

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, namenode

we have a old hadoop cluster machine hadoop - version 2.6

all machines in the cluster are redhat version - 7.3

we have a problem to start the standby name-node on the last master machine

from the logs ( *under /var/log/hadoop/hdf* ) , we can see the error - **No valid image files found**

I am not sure about my solution , but is its mean that we need to delete the files - ( *edits_inprogress_XXXXX* ) under */hadoop/hdfs/journal/hdfsha/current* , and then restart the standby name-node service ?

```
2018-01-24 16:10:27,826 ERROR namenode.NameNode (NameNode.java:main(1774)) - Failed to start namenode.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: No valid image files found
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImageTransactionalStorageInspector.getLatestImages(FSImageTransactionalStorageInspector.java:165)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.loadFSImage(FSImage.java:618)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.recoverTransitionRead(FSImage.java:289)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.loadFSImage(FSNamesystem.java:1045)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.loadFromDisk(FSNamesystem.java:703)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.loadNamesystem(NameNode.java:688)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.initialize(NameNode.java:752)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:992)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:976)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1701)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1769)
2018-01-24 16:10:27,829 INFO  util.ExitUtil (ExitUtil.java:terminate(124)) - Exiting with status 1
2018-01-24 16:10:27,845 INFO  namenode.NameNode (LogAdapter.java:info(47)) - SHUTDOWN_MSG:
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down NameNode at master03.sys573.com/102.14.22.29
************************************************************/
```

I also try with **hadoop namenode -format**

but its return with the following:

```
Could not format one or more JournalNodes. 1 exceptions thrown:
    :8485: Directory /data/hadoop/hdfs/journal/hdfsha is in an inconsistent state: Can't format the storage directory because the current directory is not empty.
```

all output:

```
18/01/24 17:36:19 ERROR namenode.NameNode: Failed to start namenode.
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.qjournal.client.QuorumException: Could not format one or more JournalNodes. 1 exceptions thrown:
:8485: Directory /data/hadoop/hdfs/journal/hdfsha is in an inconsistent state: Can't format the storage directory because the current directory is not empty.
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage$StorageDirectory.checkEmptyCurrent(Storage.java:482)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage$StorageDirectory.analyzeStorage(Storage.java:558)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.qjournal.server.JNStorage.format(JNStorage.java:185)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.qjournal.server.Journal.format(Journal.java:217)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.qjournal.server.JournalNodeRpcServer.format(JournalNodeRpcServer.java:145)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.qjournal.protocolPB.QJournalProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.format(QJournalProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:145)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.qjournal.protocol.QJournalProtocolProtos$QJournalProtocolService$2.callBlockingMethod(QJournalProtocolProtos.java:25419)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:640)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:982)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2351)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2347)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1866)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2345)
```

Comment: Have you solved the problem?